# unable to open some url in urllib2 which can still be openned in browsers?

Tags: python, urllib2

I can open this [url](http://ratedata.gaincapital.com/2014/.%5C01%20January) in firefox or chrome, but I cannot open it with urllib2.

```
>>> req = urllib2.Request(r"http://ratedata.gaincapital.com/2014/.\01 January", headers={'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.1"})
>>> urllib2.urlopen(req)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#134>", line 1, in <module>
    urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Very strange url but how can I fix this?

Comment: Probably because of the white space in "01 January". I replaced white space by %20 and it worked

Comment: Thanks @yeputons ! It has nothing to do with the cookies but requests definitely much better than urllib2 It just directly fix this problem even without header. If you can explain further about why the requests can work with url like this, I should accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace white space with `%20`

```
>>> req = urllib2.Request(r"http://ratedata.gaincapital.com/2014/.\01%20January", headers={'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.1"})
>>> urllib2.urlopen(req)
<addinfourl at 139708797193896 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x7f10820eb2d0>>
```

Comment: just use requests to fix all these problems. It needs to be requoted (`requests.utils.requote_uri`),but requests will just automatically do it.